# Tools to preprocess a big data for dashboards?

Tags: open-source, bigdata

I have a complex data set with more than 16M rows coming from the pharmaceutical industry. Regarding the data, it is saved in a sql server with more than 400 relational tables.

Data got several levels of hierarchies like province, city, postal code, person, and antigens measures, etc.

I would like to create many dashboards in order to observe the changes & trends happening. I can use Pentaho, R (shiny) or Tableau for this purpose. But the problem is data is so huge, and it take so long to process it with dashboard software. I have a choice of making cube and connect it to dashboard.

My question here is whether there are any other solutions that I can use instead of making a cube? I don't want to go through the hassle of making & maintaining a cube.

I would like to use a software where I specify relationships between tables, so the aggregation/amalgamation happens smoothly and output processed tables that can connect to dashboards. I hear Alteryx is one software that can do it for you (I haven't tried it myself, and it is an expensive one!).

I understand this task needs two or more softwares/tools. Please share your input & experience. Please mention what tools do you use, size of your data, and how fast/efficient is the entire system, and other necessary details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on how big your dataset is (not just the number of rows) and how fast your SQL server is.

I have loaded datasets with >20m rows (which are >4GB in size) directly into Tableau (though this was on 64 bit Windows machines or Macs with >8GB of RAM). And they function well.

If the amount of data is large (which means probably 10s of GB of disk space) then you are better off connecting Tableau directly to the SQL server and letting the server do the heavy lifting. This also works fine. I have billion row datasets on (fast and powerful) SQL servers where this also works at reasonable speed if the SQL server is optimized for speedy analytics rather than transaction processing.

If your local server power or capacity is limited then I'd also suggest putting your data onto something like Google's BigQuery (or Amazon's Redshift) as these are ridiculously cheap to set up and offer astonishing analytics power. Tableau has connectors for both so you can often achieve interactive speeds even with monster datasets. I have a test dataset of 500m rows and about 100GB of data where I get typical query responses for most queries in 15-30s even if I am driving them directly from Tableau.